# Program stops when I call function and displays an Exception thrown at 0x00007FFC0DCC2487 (ucrtbased.dll) error in C

Tags: arrays, c, struct, binary-search-tree

I have an array of structs. Here is my struct:

```
struct tree {
    itemType name[MAX];
    struct tree* left;
    struct tree* right;
};

typedef struct tree* treenode;
```

and I am creating this function to print out the names:

```
void printRoot(treenode root[]){

    int i = 0;
    while (root[i] != NULL) {
        printf("\n\t\t%c %s", 254, root[i]->name);
        i++;
    }
}
```

When I call my `printRoot` function, my program stops and gives me an error of `Exception thrown at 0x00007FFC0DCC2487 (ucrtbased.dll)` `0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.` and then opens up the file of stdio.h.

I tried not using a loop to see if my program really works:

```
        char folname[MAX];
        printf("Enter folder name: ");
        scanf(" %s", &folname);

        ROOT[0] = createFolder(folname);
        printf("%s", ROOT[0]->name);
```

and it does. So my assumption is that the problem is really within my `printRoot` function, but I can't seem to find out what it is that's causing it to not run.

--- [EDIT] ---
This is actually sort of a project in school in which we are to create some sort of a file explorer. So my idea is to create an array with structs in it to make a BST in each index.

we are tasked to create 3 different files: main, implementation, and header. So here is my code for more info (this is unifinished):

```
#include "Header.h"

int main() {

    treenode ROOT[50];
    char choice;

    printf("\n\t\tDo you want to create a folder? [Y/N]: ");
    scanf("%c", &choice);

    choice = tolower(choice);

    if (choice == 'y') {
        itemType folname[MAX];
        printf("\n\t\tEnter folder name: ");
        scanf(" %s", folname);

        ROOT[0] = createFolder(folname);
        printf("%s", ROOT[0]->name); //this works
        //printRoot(ROOT); --> this is the problem i'm trying to fix


    }
    else
    {
        printf("\ntest");
    }
```

implementation:

```
treenode createFolder(itemType x[]) {
    treenode touch = (struct tree*)malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
    strcpy(touch->name, x);
    touch->left = NULL;
    touch->right = NULL;

    return touch;
}

void printRoot(treenode root[]){

    int i = 0;

    while (root[i] != 0) {
        printf("\n\t\t%c %s", 254, root[i]->name);
        i++;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you place a `NULL` pointer in your array? And why do you use an array of pointers if the struct looks like a node for a tree? And what do you pass to `printRoot` at all to start with?

Comment: The problem is likely to be in the code you do not show. Please read [How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Most likely irrelevant to the error, but shouldn't `scanf(" %s", &folname);` be `scanf(" %s", folname);` instead?